# Global variable reset to 0 between classes in Android

Tags: java, android

There are a few questions related to this, but I couldn't find any that helped me. My code is below. Basically touchX is set in OnTouch. Once we get to OnDraw(), it is reset to 0.

```
public class NonmultiplierSixView extends View implements View.OnTouchListener{
int touchX;
int touchY;
public NonmultiplierSixView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    setOnTouchListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    int touchX = (int)event.getX();
    int touchY = (int)event.getY();
    Log.i("STATE", Integer.toString(touchX));
    return true;
}



@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    Log.i("STATE", Integer.toString(touchX));
}


}
```

How do I stop it from resetting the value of touchX and touchY to 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have created 2 copies of `touchX` and `touchY`.

These two,

```
public class NonmultiplierSixView extends View implements View.OnTouchListener {
int touchX;
int touchY;
```

are the instance variables (i.e. they belong to the object of class `NonmultiplierSixView`)

Whereas, the ones defined in the function `onTouch` are local copies.

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    int touchX = (int)event.getX();
    int touchY = (int)event.getY();
```

In the function `onDraw`, you are actually accessing the instance variable `touchX` and not the local variable. As instance `int` variables have default value of `0`, you are getting `0` in the `onDraw` function.

=============================================

Solution:

Try this

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    this.touchX = (int)event.getX();
    this.touchY = (int)event.getY();
    Log.i("STATE", Integer.toString(this.touchX));
    return true;
}



@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    Log.i("STATE", Integer.toString(this.touchX));
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This was very helpful. As a quick follow up question, how do you update onDraw() after the screen is touched. When I touch the screen I want it to draw certain shapes depending on where i touch it. As it is, it seems to only run onDraw once. How can I get it update onDraw() after I touch the screen? Thanks!

Comment: @mathexplorer Glad that the answer solved your problem. Please ask a new question for your followup.